# How to replace dates in a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, date

I want to fill a column with particular dates. First, I create a column of dates filled only with the date of today. Then, I compute the date I want to replace for each location. The index is in the following format: `'%Y-%m-%d'`

The computation works well. It is the last line which does not work

There is my code:

```
for j in range(1, 154):
    result['LTD_' + str(j)] = dt.date(dt.datetime.now().year,dt.datetime.now().month,dt.datetime.now().day) #creating a column of dates filled with today day
    for i in range(0, len(result.index)):
        date_selected = result.iloc[[i]].index
        date_month = add_months(date_selected,j)
        delivery_month = date_month.month
        delivery_year = date_month.year
        delivery = dt.date(delivery_year, delivery_month, result[(result.index.month == (delivery_month)) & (result.index.year == delivery_year)].index.day.min())
        delloc = result.index.get_loc(str(delivery))
        ltdloc = delloc - 3
        result.iloc[[i]]['LTD_' + str(j)] = dt.date(result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.year, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.month, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.day)
```

The last line does not work to replace the today date by the computed date. Nothing happened. date.replace generates an error.

Comment: What is error? If use instaed last row `result.iloc[[i]]['LTD_' + str(j)] = 0` it failed? If use `print(dt.date(result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.year, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.month, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.day))` it failed?

Comment: `result.iloc[[i]]['LTD_' + str(j)] = 0`, nothing happened. I have still the today date (`2017-05-25`). However, `print(dt.date(result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.year, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.month, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.day))` gives the good date in the format `'%Y-%m-%d'` I want to replace in `result.iloc[[i]]['LTD_' + str(j)]`.

Comment: Hmmm, without data it is really hard, but `result['LTD_' + str(j)].iloc[i]` or `result['LTD_' + str(j)].iloc[[i]]` should works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. How did you know?

Comment: Or better `result.loc[result.index[i], 'LTD_' + str(j)]`

Comment: I try understand what you want.

Comment: I wanted to replace a date by an other date. In my original code, I wrote `result.iloc[[i]]['LTD_' + str(j)] = dt.date(result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.year, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.month, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.day)` but it did not work. Thanks to your suggestion, I wrote instead `result['LTD_' + str(j)].iloc[[i]] = dt.date(result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.year, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.month, result.iloc[[ltdloc]].index.day)`. And it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is `ix` [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), so need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with selecting index by position:

```
result.loc[result.index[i], 'LTD_' + str(j)] = ...
```

Or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of column name:

```
result.iloc[i, result.columns.get_loc('LTD_' + str(j))] = ...
```

Another solution is:

```
result['LTD_' + str(j)].iloc[[i]] = ...
```

Comment: `result['LTD_' + str(j)].iloc[[i]]` solved my issue. Thank you very much jezrael.

Comment: I add it to answer ;)